# How to store a set of images after internal processing?

Tags: c#, image

I've been trying to save a set of image after some processing. Here is what I've been doing:
1 - Get all files from a directory
2 - Processing all them
3 - Saving

As an illustration: I have 128 images in a folder when I try process them and  save again it (the program) save just a few of them. Here is my code.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.bmp"))
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);
    string path = txtNewPath.Text+ RandonImageName + ".bmp";
    processImage(bmp).Save(path);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in `processImageCesar`? Is it there that the saving takes place? And why are you rethrowing a new exception that is less useful then the one you catched?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Hi Karl-Johan, where the saving takes places is here: processImageCesar(bmp).Save(path);. And the exception I put in order to handle any errors.

Comment: Bad idea. If you are just going to re-throw, let the original exception bubble up so you don't lose any information. We need to see your actual code (and the save function) before we can help though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the path for saving the processed images is not being changed for each image.

> string path = txtNewPath.Text+ imageName + ".bmp";

You have to change the variable `imageName` based on the current enumerated `file` variable.

Comment: Hi Mohammad. I did it. I  put the "imageName" to ilustrate what I did.

Comment: Hi. Any exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, after saving each image I added: Thread.Sleep(1000);// This way the application will wait a 1 sec before keeping on saving.

The full code is:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.bmp"))
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);
    string path = txtNewPath.Text+ RandonImageName + ".bmp";
    processImage(bmp).Save(path);    
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```